# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to negotiate key exchange for server host key algorithms

Tags: java, encryption, sshd, apache-mina

**Description:**

Trying to send requests to an application that tries to access a Netopeer2 server, but a problem happens and the key exchange fails. There are solutions out there how to configure it on the server side in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, but we want it to be on the client side that is in the application.

The application uses Apache MINA SSHD to establish the connection ([GitHub](https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd)). By default, certain algorithms are disabled. We want to enable them in that Main class below to be able to exchange `rsa-sha2-512, rsa-sha2-256` with the server. Any idea on how to do that with Apache MINA SSHD?

**The full error message says:**

```sh
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to negotiate key exchange for server host key algorithms 
(client: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss / 
server: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256)
```

**The code that throws the error:**

```java
import org.apache.sshd.client.SshClient;
import org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSession;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SshClient client = SshClient.setUpDefaultClient();
        client.start();
        try {
                ClientSession session = client.connect("root", "172.17.0.2", 830).verify(10000).getSession();
                session.addPasswordIdentity("root");
                session.auth().verify(9999);
                // error 'Unable to negotiate key exchange for server host key algorithms' is thrown
        }
        catch (IOException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below should solve the problem.

```
client.setKeyExchangeFactories(NamedFactory.setUpTransformedFactories(
        false,
        BuiltinDHFactories.VALUES,
        ClientBuilder.DH2KEX
    ));

client.setSignatureFactories(new ArrayList<>(BuiltinSignatures.VALUES))
```

For putty support

https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd/blob/master/docs/files-parsing.md

Simply add the following

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.sshd</groupId>
    <artifactId>sshd-common</artifactId>
    <version>...same version as the rest of the artifacts...</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.sshd</groupId>
    <artifactId>sshd-putty</artifactId>
    <version>...same version as the rest of the artifacts...</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not solving my own problem but I am in the same zone as you.  But for me, looking at SSHD log I think I see the client offering rsa_sha2_512 and the (one) server rejecting that and dropping the connection request.

Here is a little Scala snippet that didn't change anything for me. I think this is what you get if you don't set it; every default factory (that I found).

```
import org.apache.sshd.common.kex.{BuiltinDHFactories, KeyExchangeFactory}
 val kexList: util.List[KeyExchangeFactory] = {
        val kex = List(
          BuiltinDHFactories.dhg1,
          BuiltinDHFactories.dhg14,
          BuiltinDHFactories.dhgex,
          BuiltinDHFactories.dhg14_256,
          BuiltinDHFactories.dhg15_512,
          BuiltinDHFactories.dhg16_512,
          BuiltinDHFactories.dhg17_512,
          BuiltinDHFactories.dhg18_512,
          BuiltinDHFactories.dhgex256,
          BuiltinDHFactories.ecdhp256,
          BuiltinDHFactories.ecdhp384,
          BuiltinDHFactories.ecdhp521)
        val dh2kex = kex.map(k => ClientBuilder.DH2KEX(k))
        dh2kex.asJava
      }
      session.setKeyExchangeFactories(kexList)
```

Or this in Java:

```
    List<KeyExchangeFactory> kexList = 
BuiltinDHFactories.VALUES.stream().map(ClientBuilder.DH2KEX).collect(Collectors.toList());
```